# What are the reasons that can make a deployment in Jelastic so long?

Tags: docker, jelastic

I am using Jelastic with a public provider. Here is the thing: I have created one registry where I store my docker images (hosted in jelastic)

Then, from a manifest I deploy a database docker (my own image) located in my private registry located in jelastic BUT the deployment is very long like 15 or 20 minutes.

Do you have an idea on the reason?
my docker image is 3 GB but in previous test the deployment took 4 minutes not more.

Cheers

Comment: Are you saying that the same setup (e.g. on same Jelastic provider etc.) took 4 minutes before but now it takes 15-20 minutes? Is it possible there were substantial changes to some of the upstream labels included in your image?

Comment: No I do not think so because even if I removed the registry and redeploy it from scratch it still take the same time.. Unfortunately we do not find a lot example of manifests which describes how to fetch an image from a private docker registry

Comment: Hmm I think it's one for your provider

Comment: ok.. thank you for your answer

Comment: @SoufianeBenmalek Who is your current provider?